# Remove quasi duplicates in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python, I have a list of objects (samples), each of which is in fact made of a number of numpy arrays:

```
A = [Sample([1.,2.],3.,4,[5.,6.]),
     Sample([7.,8.],9.,10,[11.,12.]),
     Sample([13.,14.],15.,16,[17.,18.]),
     Sample([1.05,2.05],3.05,4,[5.05,6.05]),
     Sample([1.05,2.05],3.05,4,[6.,6.05])]
```

The problem I have is this set of samples can become massive, so what I intend to do is a very crude approximation: add a new sample only if it is not similar enough to the samples already stored. So, as a first approximation, I would like to remove any quasi duplicates as given by points with values within `0.1` of another for each column, i.e. lines 1 and 4 in `A` would be considered quasi duplicates, while 1 and 5 (or 4 and 5) would not.

Any advice on how I could approach the problem? I was looking for relatively efficient solutions.

I was thinking of approaching the problem as follows:

- Finding any quasi duplicates as if the list were an array;
- Once, their position is known, remove the corresponding sample entry.

I think that because I am not looking at exact duplicates and hashing is not an option, I cannot use `set()`, but I may be wrong. At the moment, my intention is to look at the problem line by line with `for` and `if` loops. Obviously, this solution is very inefficient, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about rounding the values to your required precision?

Comment: Also check numpy.isclose
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html

Comment: In order to make this efficient, you would need to have some kind of hash function, so that `A` and `B` are similar if `f(A) == f(B)`. If you managed this kind of thing, you could use an efficient data structure (e.g. a set :P). Otherwise, if you cannot do this, you will have to compare every new element with every already existing element in order to check whether it’s similar to another, and that’s very quickly very inefficient.

Comment: To merge my first comment with @poke, you can have a `__hash__` function that has the reduced precision.

Comment: Thank you! From your comments, I guess I will probably round the values (after all, I am making approximations anyway) and then I will probably be able to use `set()`.

Comment: I guess that if you write an answer, I will accept it. The hashing system after specifying a 1-digit precision did work in the end.